# Why is my JS script with SockJS and JQuery never working?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm developing a simple web messenger using Spring. I have this form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="importmap"> {
        "imports": {
          "@stomp/stompjs": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@stomp/stompjs@7.0.0/+esm",
          "sockjs-client": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.1.4/+esm"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="connect()">
    <div th:each="message : ${chat.messageList}">
      <p th:text="${message.sender.username}"></p>
      <p th:text="${message.sendingTime}"></p>
      <p th:text="${message.text}"></p>
    </div>
    <form id="message">
      <label for="messageText"> Enter your message: </label>
      <p id="userId" th:text="${userId}" hidden></p>
      <p id="username" th:text="${username}" hidden></p>
      <p id="chatId" th:text="${chatId}" hidden></p>
      <textarea id="messageText" name="text"></textarea>
      <button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      import { Stomp } from "@stomp/stompjs";
      import SockJS from "sockjs-client";

      let stompClient;
      let chatId = document.getElementById("chatId").textContent;
      let userId = document.getElementById("userId").textContent;
      let username = document.getElementById("username").textContent;

      function connect() {
        const socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/websocket");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
          console.log("Connected: " + frame);
          stompClient.subscribe("/topic/chat/" + chatId, function(message) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(message.body));
          });
        });
      }

      function sendMessage() {
        const message = {
          text: $("#messageText").val(),
          sender: {
            id: userId,
            username: username,
          },
          chat: {
            id: chatId,
          },
        };
        stompClient.send("/app/chat/" + chatId + "/send", {}, JSON.stringify(message));
      }
      $(function() {
        $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        $("#send").click(function() {
          sendMessage();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS script in it is supposed to send a message to this controller using WebSocket:

```
@MessageMapping("/{chatId}/send")
    public void sendMessage(@DestinationVariable String chatId, @Payload Message message) {
        messageService.sendMessage(message);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/chat/" + chatId, message);
    }
```

So, pressing the button "send" should call sendMessage() function, and on the loading of the page connect() should be called. But neither of those are executed, and i want to understand why.
I tried to inserting script directly in HTML (it was in other file before), and i tried to check if this script executing at all-if i put alert() at the start of the script, alert() will never happen as well, but if i delete everything but alert(), it will work.

Here's my WebSocket configuration class:

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, which part of your code is not executing? The code on client or server? Is it `sendMessage` on the client?

Comment: @DanMacak Hi, client-side code (JS functions sendMessage() and connect()) should send request on the server-side controller sendMessage, but JS code is just never even executed.

Comment: When I run your code I get an error `"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier \"@stomp/stompjs\"`. Are you getting the same?

Comment: @DanMacak No, in IntellIJ IDEA i do not see any errors anywhere.

Comment: No you should see this error in browser, or wherever you run your client-side code.

Comment: @DanMacak as i understand, error you getting is shown when stompjs is not installed properly. I have now verified, that in my project stompjs is installed by running npm install @stomp/stompjs.

Comment: I tried your code and for me `sendMessage` gets executed on the client just fine when I click the send button. Not sure if it sends the message though. Are you sure it doesn't get executed? 
As for `connect()` that doesn't execute because it is defined in a module, but modules are scoped so your `<body>` knows nothing about it. Rather use `$( document ).ready()` to define on load callback.